# Why clearing entropy count requires root privileges?

Tags: linux, random, linux-kernel

In order to clear the entropy count when using linux's /dev/random through the system call ioctl (RNDCLEARPOOL), the caller must have root privilege (according to this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c). Why is it necessary to prevent user space applications from being able to clear the entropy count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the entropy count can cause significant reductions in performance that affect processes run by all users of the system.